# Count and group containing given criteria mysql

Tags: mysql

I have data that users submit, the wordings are not exactly the same but there is a similarity see the below example

```
 ---No  | Catergory
    526 HIV
    418 HIV/AIDs
    207 RVD
    86  HIV/AIDS.
    84  HIV INFECTION
    58  HIV PATIENT ON HAART
    54  RETROVIRAL DISEASE
    44  LIPODYSTROPHY
    39  MALARIA
    36  HIV MANAGEMENT
    36  Chronic Myeloid Leukemia
```

I want to get the total count and So that all rows with HIV, H.I.V, Retro are grouped as one under category like this

```
    category | number
    ------------------
    HIV      |    1500
   ----------------------
    MALARIA  |    39
......
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Group using a `CASE` expression, something like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Category LIKE '%HIV%' OR Category LIKE '%Retro%'
         THEN 'HIV'
         ELSE Category END AS Category,
    COUNT(*) AS number
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN Category LIKE '%HIV%' OR Category LIKE '%Retro%'
         THEN 'HIV'
         ELSE Category END;
```

The exact logic you use to map the various categories into the HIV bucket might differ from what I listed above.  You might have to just use `IN` and compare against a complete list of categories to be mapped.